# What is the good practice to create a Constants file in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Java project, in which I have this `Constants` class to organise my constants:

```
/** This is my java constants file in java**/

public class Constants {
    public static final String LOWER_GROUND_FLOOR = "LG";
    public static final String GROUND_FLOOR = "G";
    public static final String FIRST_FLOOR = "1";
    public static final String SECOND_FLOOR = "2";
    public static final String THIRD_FLOOR = "3";
    public static final String THIS_KIOSK_ID = "currentFloorIndex";
    public static final String EXPIRY = "cacheExpiry";
    public static String third_floor_small_map_path = "map/abc.png";
}
```

How can I create a similar constants file in Kotlin?

Comment: 1. create a file `Constants.kt` 2. Add constant declarations to it, right at the top level. 3. Use the constants anywhere in the project, no qualificiation needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a public constant in kotlin like public static final in java, you can create it as follow.

```
companion object {

     const val MY_CONSTANT = "Constants"

}
```

Checkout this link 
https://blog.egorand.me/where-do-i-put-my-constants-in-kotlin/

Comment: You totally missed top-level constants. Your first example can be written outside any class declaration. The second example is only for special cases where you want to tie the constant specifically with a class, so it lives inside its namespace. BTW the first example as a property of a class is just bad practice, it increases each object's RAM footprint for no reason.